# CiviDesk's Google Apps Sync Extension

Tags: extension

I'm considering using CiviDesk's Google Apps Sync extension with CiviCRM 4.7 to update my domain's Directory. Since the information page (https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-apps-sync) is a bit old and light on details, I'd like to ask this community a few questions:

1. It was compatible as of civicrm 4.3. Is anyone using it with later versions?
2. On initial use, does it empty and replace your existing Google Apps Directory, add to it, or synchronize both databases.

I've also asked CiviDesk these questions and will update this post if I hear from them.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard back from CiviDesk, but I did go on github and find [version 1.1](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps) which claims compatibility with CiviCRM 4.5. I felt like that was close enough to my 4.7.3 for me to take the leap. I initially got a bunch of errors (see list below the break), but they are not persistent.

**My Results**

Success. The only errors I've spotted were due to my contacts data having undesirable unicode characters. Once corrected (By editing the table `civicdesk_sync_googleaps`) the next cron run or forced execution puts it back to work.

**What to expect in your Google Apps Directory when the sync happens:**

1. Wait 24-48 hours for the first results to appear. You can blame Google for that.
2. Pre-existing contacts are not updated or deleted. New contacts will be ADDED to the Google Apps Directory. On subsequent runs, these newly-added contacts should update as CiviCRM does (I base this on the fact that the extension records Google's own contact ID for what I can only assume will be future use).
3. Added contacts will be populated with Name, Organization, Job Title, Email, and a link to their CiviCRM profile. As far as I can tell, mailing addresses are NOT synced.
4. The default sync speed it 50 contacts per cron run. I cranked mine up to 100 with no ill effects.

That's about it. I'm including error messages below for searchability reasons for the community--I'm not expecting anyone to offer fixes especially since they were just one-time errors.

-- Just error messages below. Avoid reading further if they make you sleepy. --

Notice: Undefined index: child in _cividesk_insert_navigationMenu() (line 58 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/cividesk.ext.php).

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_email in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 142 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_key in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 142 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_secret in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 142 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: domain in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 144 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: domain in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 44 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_key in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 58 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_secret in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 63 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: last_sync in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 74 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: processed in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 75 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_email in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 142 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_key in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 142 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_secret in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 142 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: domain in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->_checkOAuth() (line 144 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: domain in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 44 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_key in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 58 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: oauth_secret in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 63 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: processed in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->buildQuickForm() (line 75 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: resetStr in CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_GoogleApps->postProcess() (line 124 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/GoogleApps.php).
Notice: Undefined index: processed in civicrm_api3_job_googleapps_sync() (line 184 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/com.cividesk.sync.googleapps-1.0/api/v3/Job/GoogleappsSync.php).

Comment: Thanks for trying this out - great for those thinking about giving it a spin. Why not create issues on the extension Github for the two (?) issues you ran into? You might get lucky and find someone fixes it for you - putting it on the radar is the first step, always worth making the effort.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense I don't know, but in my experience few 4.3 extensions work 100% with 4.7, but generally are easy to update.

I know a few people on the CiviDesk team, and I'm sure that they'd love to hear from you if you haven't contacted them directly: https://www.cividesk.com/contact-us

John

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to install your Civicrm "CiviDesk's Google Apps Sync Extension", but I met some problem to understand the values I need to set in the setup page.

In detail:

- I use the 4.7 Civicrm version
- I created a new OAuth 2.0
- in the "OAuth key" I set the Google "ID Client" (or other values as the "Name")
- in the "OAuth secret" I set the Google "Client secret"

In any case I always obtain the message "*Cannot authenticate to this Google Apps domain. Check OAuth parameters*".

Comment: I recently reactivated my extension after having it turned off for a few months. When I switched it back on I got the same error you noted, which leads me to wonder if there was a change at Google's end that is affecting compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the power of CiviCRM 5.4.0 with CiviDesk's Google Apps Sync Extension. This is still the version 1.0 of 2013.
Then like [marcello](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/2656/marcello) and [Eric H](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/635/eric-h) I still obtain the message "Cannot authenticate to this Google Apps domain. Check OAuth parameters".
I contacted Google and trying to clarify an issue of trailing "space" at the end of both the ID client and the secret. Can this be the culprit?

I let you informed of the Google answer on the case.
Ichi

Comment: I also contacted the Team of the CiviDesk team: https://www.cividesk.com/contact-us I let you informed of the CiviDesk answer on this issue. Ichi